# XNA (BEPU) Physics Performance

Tags: xna, c#, physics, xbox360

Im using XNA 4.0 with the BEPU physics engine v1.2 and I have encountered some performance problems on Xbox. Im not sure if the my mesurements are an expected result of the Xbox (with alot of dynamic physics objects). ***So I wonder if anyone else thinks the numbers are fair or not?***

Here's my mesurement:

[image]

Im runing a simulation with 100 dynamic boxes and a static plane as my ground. Now this sim is multithreaded on hardware threads 1, 3, 4 and 5 (Xbox) and I see a significant perf boost because of that. However the performance of the simulation varies between 3-5.5 ms for **resting** objects on the 360. 
Is that not way to much or is it fair? The PC version runs the sim at about 0.7-1 ms. However that version is multithreaded over 8 cores. But it's still a very big leap.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My fault as usually.

If you're using BEPU Physics. Be aware that some events don't check for changes before they fire, causing an internal loop, resulting in terrible performance.

In my case setting the position to the exactly same position again (wich happens in some cases) fires this kind of infinit update loop and drops performance.

This performance hit will be even more noticable on the Xbox because of the poor floating point performance.